# SQL join by multiple many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, join

**I have the following tables:**

subjects

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| subject_1 | Subject 1 |
| subject_2 | Subject 2 |
| subject_3 | Subject 3 |

tests

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| test_1 | Test 1 |
| test_2 | Test 2 |

quizzes

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| quiz_1 | Quiz 1 |

questions

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| question_1 | Question 1 |

**And junction tables:**

subjects_tests

| subject | test |
| --- | --- |
| subject_1 | test_1 |
| subject_2 | test_2 |

subjects_quizzes

| subject | quiz |
| --- | --- |
| subject_3 | quiz_1 |

tests_questions

| test | question |
| --- | --- |
| test_1 | question_1 |
| test_2 | question_1 |

quizzes_questions

| quiz | question |
| --- | --- |
| quiz_1 | question_1 |

**I know the question id. As a result I want to get:**

| question.title | test.title | quiz.title | subject.title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | Test 1 | null | Subject 1 |
| Question 1 | Test 2 | null | Subject 2 |
| Question 1 | null | Quiz 1 | Subject 3 |

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

```
select q.Title as questionTitle,
       t.Title as testTitle,
       null    as quizTitle,
       s.Title as subjectTitle
from questions q
         inner join tests_questions tq on q.id = tq.question
         inner join tests t on t.id = tq.test
         inner join subjects_tests st on t.id = st.test
         inner join subjects s on s.id = st.subject
-- where q.id = 'question_1'
union all
select q.Title as questionTitle,
       null    as testTitle,
       qz.Title as quizTitle,
       s.Title as subjectTitle
from questions q
         inner join quizzes_questions qq on q.id = qq.question
         inner join quizzes qz on qz.id = qq.quiz
         inner join subjects_quizzes sq on qz.id = sq.quiz
         inner join subjects s on s.id = sq.subject
-- where q.id = 'question_1'
;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5b724246bbea23ce06084f8b2a77761)